# Assigning to a List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to assign values to a list in C#. I have the following classes:

```
public class Request
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public List<Service> services { get; set; }

}
public class Service
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string did { get; set;}
}
```

I'm using the following code in my controller:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCases()
    {
        var client = await 
        SalesforceService.GetUserNamePasswordForceClientAsync();

        //Select All Cases Where Status = New.
        var cases = await client.QueryAsync<Case>("SELECT Id,
        Description FROM Case Where Status='New'");
        var sfCases = cases.Records.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Description
        });

        List<Request> requestresults = new List<Request>();
        foreach (var c in sfCases)
        {

            var sfrequest = new Request();
            if (c.Description != null)
            {
                string[] descriptionline = null;

                sfrequest.Description = c.Description;

                descriptionline = Regex.Split(c.Description, "\r\n");

                if (descriptionline.Any(x => x.Contains("FirstName")))
                {
                    var firstnameindex = Array.FindIndex(descriptionline, row => row.Contains("FirstName"));
                    sfrequest.firstName = descriptionline[firstnameindex].Replace("FirstName - ", "");

                    var lastnameindex = Array.FindIndex(descriptionline, row => row.Contains("LastName"));
                    sfrequest.lastName = descriptionline[lastnameindex].Replace("LastName - ", "");

                    var emailindex = Array.FindIndex(descriptionline, row => row.Contains("Email"));
                    sfrequest.email = descriptionline[emailindex].Replace("Email - ", "");

                    var skuindex = Array.FindIndex(descriptionline, row => row.Contains("sku"));
```

How do I grab the `sku` and `did` and assign them the same way I did the other properties?

Comment: What and where is your problem exactly? Highlight it in the code..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking question try to make a [Minimal complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your issue. Right now you have a lot of code that probably does not have much to do with the issue. As @Coding stated above it is unclear what the problem is right now. This is not easy, but it is part of working with software.

Answer (score -1):

As your request class contains a list that is called `services`, you can simply access the values of services like:

`services.sku` 
`services.did`

Within your source code, I assume you would use it like:

```
var skuindex = Array.FindIndex(descriptionline, row => row.Contains("sku"));
sfrequest.services.sku = descriptionline[skuindex].Replace("Sku - ", "");

var didindex = Array.FindIndex(descriptionline, row => row.Contains("did"));
sfrequest.services.did = descriptionline[didindex].Replace("Did - ", "");
```

Additionally I have to point out two things: 
- Make sure that the`services`-variable is initialized at the point you are trying to access it, otherwise you run into exceptions. 
- It is recommended to use uppercase for the first letter of property-names. The notation that you used is usually used for fields.